# How to dynamically update the contents of a div in HTML and maintain the previous style?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have made a dashboard using Flask (Python) that displays the images present on a folder in my Desktop. Now, that folder is going to be updated with new images every 5 seconds or so and that's why I would like to update my website with the new images. I figured that using Javascript/Jquery AJAX would be best for smooth user experience. I succesfully managed to update my dashboard every 2 seconds using Jquery as shown in the following code.

However my problem is loss of styling. As you can see in the 1st screenshot , the Jumbotron is perfectly inside the inner boundary. But in the 2nd image you can see that the entire central portion of the website including the Jumbotron and the images shift slightly from centre. The red marking on the image indicates the shift. So, I wanted to know how can I prevent Jquery from changing my style. I want the refreshed page to replace the previous page as it is.

Here are my codes -

Flask `routes.py` -

```
@app.route('/image/<im>')
@login_required
def image(im):
    image_src=[im+'/'+i for i in  os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder,im))]
    rows=math.ceil(len(image_src)/3)
    print(image_src)
    return render_template('dashboard.html',title='Welcome',images=image_src,rows=rows,image_date=im)
```

HTML -  `dashboard.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<hr>
<div class="container dash-container main-body image-area" >
    <div class="row">
        <br>
        <hr >
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="jumbotron ">
                <h1 id="hdr">DASHBOARD</h1>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

{% if images %}

<div class="row" id="info">

    <a href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="info">
            {% set ns = namespace(counter=0) %}
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered images-table" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                {% for row in range(rows) %}
                <tr class="image-hover">
                    {% for data in range(3) %}
                        {% if ns.counter  < images|length %}
                            <td style="width:10%;">
                                <a href="{{ url_for('display',file=images[ns.counter][10:],folder=images[ns.counter][0:10]) }}"><img src="{{ url_for('static',filename=images[ns.counter]) }}" alt="User Image" width="220" height="220"></a>
                                <br>
                                {% set ns.counter = ns.counter + 1 %}
                            </td>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endif %}


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
   $('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}");
}, 2000)

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

The HTML file basically arranges the images in rows with max items of 3 per row.

CSS - `dashboard.css`

```
#info{
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'Saira',sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

.dash-container{
    height: 100%;
}
.images-table{ 
    width: auto !important;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

.folder-link {
    color:black /*#1cd1ff*/;
    font-size: 30px;
}

table tr.row-hover:hover{
    background-color: #190101;

}
table tr.row-hover:hover .folder-link{
    color:white;
}
table tr.image-hover:hover .folder-link{
    color:black;
}

table tr.row-hover:hover .folder-link:hover{
    color:#00ff83;
}

table.images-table tr.image-hover:hover{
    background-color: black;
}
table.images-table tr.image-hover td:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here are the Images . `Image 1` is the default website without any `javascript` and `Image 2` is the website after `ajax` calls.

[image: See the red indication on top right. This image has the jumbotron perfectly aligned inside the central border.]

[image: Notice the arrows on top right. That's where the deviation takes place. It looks as if the entire central portion has been moved out to the right.]

I want the refreshed page to perfectly overwrite the previous view and not produce the shift from center.

Please help.

---

EDIT 1:

I have noticed that if i replace the class selector in Jquery with 'body' tag, the styling is retained. However, unlike previous type, the page refresh takes atleast 3x  more time.

```
$('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}");
```

changed to

```
$('body').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}");
```

Here is my `base.html` code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {{ moment.include_jquery() }}
    {{ moment.include_moment() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/base.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/about.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/index.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/dashboard.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/display.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/feedback.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/login.css') }}">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira" rel="stylesheet">
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Welcome_segregator</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top  navbar-custom">
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="navbar-header">

            {% if current_user.username %}
            <a class="navbar-brand nav-custom" href="{{ url_for('index') }}" ><span id="header"><span id="logo"><strong>Welcome </strong></span id="header"><strong>{{ current_user.username|striptags }} !</strong></span></a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="navbar-brand nav-custom" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span id="header"><span id="logo"><strong>Welcome </strong></span></span></a>
            {% endif %}
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right " >
            <li class="nav-custom"><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home "> <span id="header"><strong>Home</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"> <span id="header"><strong>Dashboard</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('about') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> <span id="header"><strong>About Us</strong></span></a></li>
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('feedback') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"> <span id="header"><strong>Feedback</strong></span></a></li>
            {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('login') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> <span id="header"><strong>Login</strong></span></a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a class="nav navbar-nav" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"> <span id="header"><strong>Logout</strong></span></a></li>
            {% endif %}

    </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but everytime you `load` with `.image-area` are you not actually inserting the html _**inside**_ the `image-area` div instead of replacing the div?

Comment: Yeah you are probably right. I figured out the solution by creating a parent div that encloses all other divs in dashboard.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above: I think your current call to `$('.image-area').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}");` is causing you to get nesting `.image-area` divs.

Try switching

`{% block content %}{% endblock %}`

to

`<div id='img-cont'>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>`

And then change your js to

`$('.img-cont').load("{{ url_for('image',im=image_date) }}");`

Comment: Yeah it works. However, I created a parent div inside  the { % block content %}  which enclosed all other code in dashboard.HTML . It worked.

Comment: Nice, I still think you'll be getting nested divs that way though, so just check for that, as it may trip you up again down the line.

Comment: You are right probably. I'll take care of that but for this problem either solution works.